# PHP running out of memory during while loop

Tags: php, memory, while-loop

I have a PHP script that finds either a jpg or mp4 file in a specific directory where the files are called `1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.mp4 etc`. My script (below) is running out of memory after the fourth file, the system needs to reliably be able to sort through hundreds of files.

```
<?php
    set_time_limit(0);
    print_r(scandir(substr(realpath("index.php"), 0, -10)));
    $ia = count(scandir(substr(realpath("index.php"), 0, -10)));
    $ia = ($ia / 2) - 1;
    echo $ia;

    $i = 1;
    while(!($i == $ia)) {
        $i++;
        if(file_get_contents($i.'.jpg')) {
            echo '<div class="item"><a href="'.$i.'/"><img src="'.$i.'.jpg" height="98px" alt="Upload"></a></div>';
        }
        if(file_get_contents($i.'.mp4')) {
            echo '<div class="item"><a href="'.$i.'/"><video src="'.$i.'.mp4" height="98px" autoplay loop></video></a></div>';
        }
        flush();
    }
?>
```

Comment: Try to check file existence with `file_exists`

Comment: I think what @u_mulder means is that instead of `file_get_contents` which loads the whole thing in memory, use `file_exists` to check for the existence.

Comment: Solved the problem! Thanks!